# Making Django forms return forms.instance in templates

Tags: django, django-forms

I have complex user-defined permissions for my users. But to make thinks simpler, let's imagine there's only `read-only` or `write` permissions for each user.

I am using Django forms to edit and save model objects. And **my goal** is to render `<input>` in the Django HTML template for those users who have the permission to edit a given model instance, and a hard-coded data (without `<input>` tag) if the user has only read-only permission.

Currently, I have the following code in my Django template to achieve this:

```
{%if user.has_permission_to_edit %}
    {{my_form.my_field}}
{% else %}
    {{my_form.instance.my_field}}
{% endif %}
```

And here's `my_form`:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control input-sm'
            if field.required == True: 
                field.widget.attrs['required'] = ''
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('my_field',)
```

The problem with the code in the template is that I have to use multiple {% if %}{% else %} blocks. I am relatively new to Django, and I know that there is plethora of advanced tools making Django code potentially super DRY, so I want to asked you guys, what is the most DRY method to organize what I described in the template. Specifically, is there any way to make Django forms return instance values based on some condition specified inside the form definition? Or do I have to some used-defined tag ? Or maybe some totally different architecture is used to achieve such goals?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve? Are you editing a model object? How does the behaviour change if the user has permission to edit?

Comment: Which type of field is it where you want to display the hardcoded values? Is it a text field?

Comment: Well, it can be text field, numeric value, checkbox...Anything. Based on the type of respective model field type

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood form your question, you want to pass the instance of the data fetched from your data-source.

```
from .forms import MyForm
from django.shortcuts import render
```

assuming you have created a forms.py file at the views.py level.

Fetching data from data-source(Detail is the model in below example)

```
detail_instance = Detail.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
reg_form = MyForm(instance=detail_instance or None)
# In case of edit scenario you can pass in the post params to the form as well
reg_form = MyForm(request.POST, instance=detail_instance)
# Or form with uploads
reg_form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=detail_instance)
```

Now once we have data inside our reg_form parameter we can pass it in the template

```
return render(request, 'applicant/register.html', { 'my_form' : reg_form})
```

Do whatever you wish, with you my_form variable in the template.

**BASED ON THE UPDATED QUESTION**

You can pass parameter to the init function of a form

```
reg_form = MyForm(exist = exist, some_param = param_value, instance=detail_instance or None)
```

After passing the param, the param can be fetched and processed in the init function of the form

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exist = kwargs.pop('exist', None)
        pk_reg = kwargs.pop('param', None)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #do some stuff with you custom params here
        if exist == True or pk_reg:
            self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

The above approach has an alternative as well for having separate forms for separate permission and calling the appropriate form based on the user permissions.